# WIndows 10, connect an external SATA drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, sata-to-usb

I'm connecting to Windows 10 a SATA drive (SSD) using the SATA-to-USB(3) cable

[image]

The drive has 2 partitions

1. Linux ext4 (200 GB)
2. FAT32 (50 GB)

Windows sees the drive fine in `Disk Management`.

But it shows the partition 2 as `Healthy 50 GB`, doesn't recognize the fat32 format (seemingly) and, of of course, doesn't mount it (doesn't appear in Drives).

So, reading the forums,

- On Linux, copied the partition 2 data somewhere
- re-formatted that partition 2 as `NTFS`
- copied back the data from somewhere to that new fresh NTFS partition

but unfortunately Windows 10 still doesn't recognize it as a NTFS drive.

- Is there some security issue that needs to be addressed?
- Is the first partition being ext4 makes Windows cough?
- I tried to connect the drive to a USB2 - same problem
- Now that I think about it, the <s>partition table is GPT</s> (Actually it's MBR!)

[ Note that the drive via SATA2USB works fine on Linux, for instance ]

**edit**

Screenshot of the `Disk Management` interface.

The `Change Drive Letter and Paths...` feature is grayed out...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What you need to do to be able to access your drive in file explorer is to assign it a letter in Disk Management**

1. Open `Disk Management`
2. Right-click on the **Healthy 50GB** partition
3. Choose **Change Drive Letter and Paths....**
4. In the next window that comes up, click on **Add..**
5. You will see that the **Assign the following drive letter** radio button is already selected
6. To the right of that there is a drop down menu option to choose your new drive letter (or just leave it at whatever it defaults to)
7. Click **OK** and you're done

You will now be able to access that drive in file explorer

[image]

*Edit: from your additional edit above it would appear as if that partition is currently hidden and needs to be manually set to an NTFS partition identifier. To manually change this in diskpart do the following:*

- Open a **Command Prompt** as **Administrator**
- Type `diskpart` and hit **Enter**. You should now have a `diskpart>` prompt
- Type `list disk` . Identify the disk number of the disk in question from the list it returns
- Now type `select disk x` (x being the number of the disk you identified in the previous step)
- Now type `list partitio`n . Identify the partition number of the partition you want to unhide.
- Now type `select partition x` (x being the partition number you identified in the previous step)
- Now type `set id = 07 override` (07 is the NTFS partition identifier)
- If successful it should return a message saying

  DiskPart successfully set the partition ID
- Now go back to **Disk Management** and the option to change the drive letter should no longer be grayed out

Comment: Oh, I should trust a Windowser... using `diskpart` and forcing the ID to `NTFS` did the trick instantly! Well done, Mr White!